# instant binding method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I have this simple app for rebar selection. I have used bindings to set the connections and also there are some data called at the start from array controller. I am running this method after button calculate is pressed which gets the values from NSForm cell and use it for further calculation:

```
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{
NSArray *editFields = [formular cells];
int vArea;
vArea = [[editFields objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
NSMutableString *select = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"You selected %d + 25 = %d",vArea,vArea+25];
[selected setStringValue:select];

}
```

It is running ok however I would like to run this code instantly after row in table is selected so I do not need that button there but I do not know which method to use as I am still learning.

[image: scrennshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just learning too, so this may not be the best way to do it.  If your class is set as the delegate for NSTableView you could implement the following method.

The Table View will inform the delegate (your class) that its selection has changed, at which point you can do your calculation.

```
    - (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        int row;
        row = [myTable selectedRow];

        if (row == -1) 
        {
            NSLog(@"No Row selected");
        } 
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"Selected Row = %d", row);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was so simple. I just assign IBAction to my tableView object and its working now instantly. Sorry for this post I will think more throughly before posting anything here.